# Recyclerviewer when scroll page space occure

Tags: android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="fragments.ProfileFragment">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/cover_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:gravity="center">
            <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_cover"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"/>
                <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:foregroundGravity="center"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_edit_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/edit_profile"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#00f"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

First time recyclerviewers seems ok. But
When i scroll the page, recyclerviewer' s rows has space occure between them.
How can i fix this problem ?

I set the recyclerviewer's height as wrap_content but it doesn' t work, also i tried with match_parent

[image]

Comment: change the row xml height to wrap_content and recyclerview height to match parent

Comment: @SabeerMohammed thanks it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem in my application. After some time I got the solution. There is a bug in recyclerView that is version specific.

Then I tried to compile another version of that and got fixed

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
```

May this solve your problem to ... try it.